# Nifi connect to sql server kerberos

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to configure connection from `Nifi` to `Sql Server` which has authentication as `Active Directory - Universal with MFA support`. I've looked over internet but i still have problems to configure it properly.

That's what i've done so far:

```
-> I've created "Execute SQL" processor
-> Database Connection pooling services 
-> New and in properties:
```

Connection Url according to this template:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<myservername>;database=<mydatabase>;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;
database driver class name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
database driver location: \mypath\
database user: user@mydomain.com
password: mypassword
```

in processor i receive such error:

> Cannot create PollableCOnnection(Cannot login with kerberos principial
>   user@mydomain.com, check your credentials. Kerberos login failed:
>   Integreated authentication failed

Having such error i started to look over internet on different pages i found that that there should be also two files created:

```
krb5.ini
jaas.conf
```

So i did like that:

in `\conf` folder of `nifi` (not sure if should be here ebcause it was not mentioned where to place those files)

i created both files with such content:

**krb5.ini:**

```
[libdefaults]  
default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM 
dns_lookup_realm = false  
dns_lookup_kdc = true  

[domain_realm]  
.mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM  

[realms]  
MYDOMAIN.COM = {  
  kdc = MYDOMAIN.COM 
  admin_server = MYDOMAIN.COM
  master_kdc = MYDOMAIN.COM
  default_domain= MYDOMAIN.COM
}
```

**jaas.conf:**

```
SQLJDBCDriver {      
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required doNotPrompt=false
useTicketCache=false;   
};
```

**then in bootstrap.conf i've added two lines:**

```
java.arg.17=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\nifi\conf\jaas.conf

java.arg.18=-Djava.security.krb5.conf=C:\nifi\conf\krb5.ini
```

**in nifi.properties file i did:**

```
# kerberos #
nifi.kerberos.krb5.file=C:\nifi\conf\krb5.ini

# kerberos service principal #
nifi.kerberos.service.principal=nifi/user@mydomain.com
nifi.kerberos.service.keytab.location=
```

Nevertheless still same and it not work. Can anyone help me out what is wrong?

Comment: any feedback anyone?

Comment: i tried also with simple url connection whch according to microsoft doc should be enough without any additional krb5 files like that: jdbc:sqlserver://servername=myservername;databasename=somedatabase;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;userName=myuser@wgatever.com;password=somepassword howvere still and issue saying like: make sure sql server is accessible and allowing tcp/ip connection on that port.